# Embedded Facebook Videos

Tags: javascript, facebook, video

I have a website with list of videos (text links). On click using jQuery I load the videos on a fancybox.

The videos used to play with sound. But recently it no longer plays with sound. The user has to manually unmute. I am not sure why the behaviour changed now.

After reading some documentation and posts here I created app ID and added the following code to the onclick jQuery function.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '111111111111',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
      });

      var my_video_player;
      FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
        if (msg.type === 'video') {
          my_video_player = msg.instance;
          my_video_player.play();
          my_video_player.unmute();
        }
      });
    };
```

The above code works on the first click. On the subsequent clicks on other video links does not load the video. But the first video will load.

How can I use the above code to work multiple times inside a onclick function (without reloading the page)?

Comment: You can not initialize the JS SDK more than once. The `fbAsyncInit` won’t fire any more, even if you execute this code multiple times. But you should not need to do that in the first place, once you subscribed for events you should get them even if they occur on a player inserted only later.

Comment: But it does not work the second time. I also tried wrapping the above code with:     if (typeof my_video_player === 'undefined' || my_video_player === null)     to avoid executing more than once.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible with the code you have shown so far. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added the full code of the onclick function to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is that window.fbAsyncInit is unreliable in Safari 11. Most of the time it does not load. Since I am on MAC & testing with Safari, I thought something was wrong with the javascript code.

It works in other desktop browsers. In Android, Brave browser could not load FB video.

All in all FB video is a bad idea for production sites. Moving videos to YouTube!

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '111111111111',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
  });

  var my_video_player;
  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'video') {
      my_video_player = msg.instance;
      my_video_player.play();
      my_video_player.unmute();
    }
  });
};
```